# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE - public variables

Tags: php

```
Class Config{
public $levels            = 10;
public $points_difference = 100;
public $diff_level        = 3;
public $timer_seconds     = 60;
public $maxBonus          = 0;
public $maxScore          = 0;
public $maxTotalScore     = 0;
public $pointsLevel       = $this->points_difference * $this->diff_level;
}
```

I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE error on the last line.
Any thoughts?

Comment: you should write this in constructor. `public $pointsLevel       = $this->points_difference * $this->diff_level;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$this` keyword during initialisation.

You need to use a constructor if you need so.

```
Class Config{
    public $levels            = 10;
    public $points_difference = 100;
    public $diff_level        = 3;
    public $timer_seconds     = 60;
    public $maxBonus          = 0;
    public $maxScore          = 0;
    public $maxTotalScore     = 0;

    public $pointsLevel; //no initialisation here

    function __construct() {
          $this->pointsLevel       = $this->points_difference * $this->diff_level;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$this` on property's
Using from following solution:

```
<?php
class Config
{

    public $levels            = 10;
    public $points_difference = 100;
    public $diff_level        = 3;
    public $timer_seconds     = 60;
    public $maxBonus          = 0;
    public $maxScore          = 0;
    public $maxTotalScore     = 0;
    public $pointsLevel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$pointsLevel = $this->points_difference * $this->diff_level;
    }
}
```